# Is the Query correct? Any Alternate to this?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

```
insert into <table_name>(<column_name_1>) values(<value>) 
where column_name_0=xyz;
```

I know this ways it's wrong but I want to find the alternate of this query.
Actually I want to insert value to that column only in which the where condition satisfies. Also I have set column_name_0 as primary key and not null

Comment: You can't do that with basic SQL. You will have to make a `ProcStock` or a `Trigger` to obtain a similar behavior. The database expects you to just NOT INSERT if you do not want to insert a record.

Comment: can you provide me with the query for the trigger to do so?

Comment: You want to update an existing record that satisfies the `where` condition? Otherwise, if you really want to *insert*, which record you want the `where` clause to conform with?

Comment: Okey I got the work done with update query!! thanks @trincot